Apk won't install when side loading
I'm developing a Flutter app, and all of a sudden I can't install it through side loading. I've tried with several devices and emulators.
The app installs just fine when using adb or flutter install. It is signed properly with a key that expires some time 2051.
When I install it using flutter install or adb install it installs on all these devices without problem. But if I put the same apk on the device and try to sideload it (installing it through the files app or chrome after downloading it), it just says "package appears to be invalid" or "you can't install the app on your device".
The devices are allowing side loading ( I can install other apk's).
The package name has not changed, and the problem appears on devices that never had the app installed and on devices that had it installed.
I have no idea how to figure out what's happening. "package appears to be invalid" is not a very exhaustive error. Especially when the apk CAN be installed with adb or flutter, just not when installing the apk directly.
Anyone with any ideas how I can move on with this problem?
My app/buil.gradle
plugins {
id "com.android.application"
id "kotlin-android"
id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"

}
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
localProperties.load(reader)
}
}
def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
keystorePropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
keystoreProperties.load(reader)
}
}
def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
flutterVersionCode = '1'
}
def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}
android {
compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion
ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}

kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = '1.8'
}

sourceSets {
    main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
}

defaultConfig {
    // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
    applicationId "xx.xxxx.xxxx"
    // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
    // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
    minSdkVersion 23
    targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
    versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
    versionName flutterVersionName
    multiDexEnabled = true
}

signingConfigs {
    release {
        keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
        keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
        storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
        storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
    }
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    }


}
flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.10"
    implementation("androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1")
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:18.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:18.3.0'
}
 


when you install through ide it installs debug apk and in sideload it may be production apk. Have you tried installing debug apk by sideloading? please post your [project]/android/app/build.gradle

@Dev Added my build.gradle now. I tried removing my signingConfig and changed to  signingConfigs.debug so it would build with debug. Same problem. This is an app we've been working on for a year and signing did work a couple of months ago. Maybe something broke when upgrading flutter...
